# Issues while connecting psql

Tags: linux, postgresql, opensuse

I installed postgresql in accordance with the instructions given at: http://xadmin.info/?p=284

```
# pg_ctl -D /var/lib/pgsql/data -l pglog.log start
server starting
postgres@linux-p0pl:~> psql
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on
 Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I am not getting as to why am I getting this error when the server has started...can someone please please help.

My pglog.log file shows the following output:

```
2013-02-06 19:43:39 GMT   FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
2013-02-06 19:43:39 GMT   HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 23971) running in data directory "/var/lib/pgsql/data"?
2013-02-06 19:44:02 GMT   FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
2013-02-06 19:44:02 GMT   HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 23971) running in data directory "/var/lib/pgsql/data"?
2013-04-24 12:43:29 GMT   FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/pgsql/data" has group or world access
2013-04-24 12:43:29 GMT   DETAIL:  Permissions should be u=rwx (0700).
2013-04-24 12:44:07 GMT   FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/pgsql/data" has group or world access
2013-04-24 12:44:07 GMT   DETAIL:  Permissions should be u=rwx (0700).
2013-04-24 12:57:02 GMT   FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/pgsql/data" has group or world access
2013-04-24 12:57:02 GMT   DETAIL:  Permissions should be u=rwx (0700).
2013-04-24 12:57:40 GMT   FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/pgsql/data" has group or world access
2013-04-24 12:57:40 GMT   DETAIL:  Permissions should be u=rwx (0700).
```

ps -ef | grep postgres

```
root     21659 21591  0 19:14 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto postgres
```

Answer (score 20):

The permissions and ownership on `/var/lib/pgsql/data` should be:

```
# ll -d /var/lib/pgsql/data
drwx------. 15 postgres postgres 4096 Apr 24 10:27 /var/lib/pgsql/data
```

If they are not do as root:

```
# chmod -R 700 /var/lib/pgsql/data
# chown -R postgres /var/lib/pgsql/data
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying. But even after changing permission and ownership it is giving me the same error..psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
 Is the server running locally and accepting
 connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Comment: postgres was working fine before I changed the pg_hba.conf file to: # TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust

Comment: I tried to restore the above changes from trust to ident and peer..however my error persists

Comment: The last error from the pglog.log you posted is about permissions. Is it the same now? Did you change pg_hba as the postgres user?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now my problem w.r.t psql is indeed solved. Can you also help me with this...I am now getting the error "FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"". Even though I changed ph_hba's method to trust still I am getting the error of authentication failure. Thanks a lot again..hope u will also solve this problem of mine...please please

Comment: As soon as I restart the server after making the changes with rcpostgresql restart..I again start getting the same error as posted in the question

Comment: @user What are the last errors in pglog.log? When you saved pg_hba as root it became unreadable by postgres which is (or should be) the user the postgresql processes run as. Only edit those files as postgres. Check the permissions and ownership or just run the commands in my answer again.

Answer (score 1):

Check in the `pglog.log` file to ensure that the server did actually start without error.  Given the error it seems like it did not start properly.

Comment: I have posted my pglog.log file's content. Hope that will help u in helping me further

Comment: It's listing a number of fatal errors regarding permissions so I would check that first as well as ensuring that a separate Postgres process is not already running which the logs also note.

Comment: how do i check that an stop the separate postgres process

Comment: The `postmaster.pid` file should contain the process ID and then you can check to see if that process is still running.

Comment: To add to my last comment the PID is listed on the first line in `postmaster.pid`.

Comment: postmaster.pid file does not exist on my system. My system gives "pg_ctl: PID file "/var/lib/pgsql/data/postmaster.pid" does not exist"..now how do i check

Comment: Can you try `ps -ef | grep postgres` and see if any processes are running that way?

Comment: root     21606 21591  0 19:06 pts/0    00:00:00 su - postgres
postgres 21607 21606  0 19:06 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash
postgres 21648 21607  0 19:08 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -ef
postgres 21649 21607  0 19:08 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto postgres

Comment: The above is the output which it gives me

Comment: root     21659 21591  0 19:14 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto postgres  is the output which i get..sorry for the previous output

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't have your server configured to put unix domain sockets in "/tmp". It's probably somewhere like "/var/run/pgsql" but see your `postgresql.conf` file to see exactly what.

Then you can specify this directory as a "host" on the command-line:

```
psql -h /path/we/want ...
```

If that's not the problem, check the port number.

Not sure why/how your psql client and postgresql server have different default paths, but then I've never heard of the site you got the instructions from, so I've no idea how useful they are.

Comment: With psql -h localhost. I get:
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
 Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
 Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Comment: Thanks for helping. Hopefully the above command will help you in helping me further

Comment: No. Because you've switched from domain sockets to tcp/ip via localhost. Get a coffee, find your postgresql.conf file and read through it and the configuration section of the online manuals.

Comment: I have uncommented my listen_address='localhost' and port=5432 in postgresql.conf...still i am getting the same error. I know this may sound insane but I am a novice at postgresql..therefore pls please excuse